# How can I access each individual property of a knockout template?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockoutJS template:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'Rows', foreach: model.items }">  </tbody>
```

and its using :

```
<script type="text/html" id="Rows">
<tr>
    <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.model.Reasons, value: ReissueReason"></select></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: ReissueRoad" class="lookUpRoads"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: HoursReissued"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: TimeRate"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: ReissuePaymentAmount"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: Comment" style="width: 300px"></td>
</tr>
```

In the Server model class I have a list that creates three 'items' so that the template has 3 rows on the screen.
I am trying to access the individual row data, for example I need to write a function that fires onBlur when a user enters a value into the HoursReissued input box, and captures the information for that item class. (C# - models.item[0])
I also need to be able to update the other fields in the row based on the onblur function - eg: the ReissuePaymentAmount should be automatically updated based on the values of the HoursReissued and TimeRate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin so you can add behavior to your data:

for example:

```
function ItemRow(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    //a computed will automatically update whenever any of it's dependencies change.
    this.ReissuePaymentAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.HoursReissued() * this.TimeRate();
    }, this);
}
var mapping = {
    'items': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new ItemRow(options.data);
        }
    }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Also see this stack overflow question, it's basically the same thing.
[Inserting a knockout computed observable in an observableArray that is generated with the ko.mapping plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139840/inserting-a-knockout-computed-observable-in-an-observablearray-that-is-generated)